# Settlers of Catan Cities and knights - Knights VS Barbarians

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

From the official [introduction video](https://youtu.be/GWUbqof61dg?t=360) of Settlers of Catan Cities & Knights, it mentioned that if barbarians value is "equal" or less than the knights value, catan wins. If there's a tie, each one player gets a progress card.

So doesn't "eqaul" values of barbarians and knights = a tie?

Often, the overall amount of knights value is the same as the cities (barbarian value), and in that case, player with more knights cover those with extra cities, which is a win or tie?

And in that case, do we all get progress card? or does that player who has the most knights get 1 VP?

Answer (score 9):

First, you check if Catan wins or not by comparing the strength of the barbarians (the number of cities) against strength of the knights (the sum of the value of active knights). In the event of a tie in the strengths, Catan wins.

If the barbarians win, the player who contributed the least has one of their cities pillaged. In the event of a tie for the lowest contribution, all players who contributed the least have one of their cities pillaged.

If Catan wins, the player who contributed the most gets a Defender of Catan card worth 1 VP. In the even of a tie for the highest contribution, all players who contributed the most get a progress card of their choice instead.

Comment: So if we have 4 players where: 
Player A has 1 city, 1 activated knight, 
Player B has 1 city, 1 activated knight, 
Player C has 2 cities, 1 activated knight, 
Player D has 1 city, 2 activated knights, 

And this is a tie, which catan wins.

Since we have 5 vs 5, no city is pillaged. And Player C gets 1 VP for contributing the most knights for this round of attack, right?

Comment: And In the case of: 
Player A has 1 city, 1 activated knight, 
Player B has 1 city, 1 activated knight, 
Player C has 2 cities, 2 activated knights, 
Player D has 2 cities, 2 activated knights, 

This is also a tie, and catan also wins.

But, Player C & D both get progress card of their choice instead of VPs, right?

Comment: @Jeff contributions are in the form of knights, not cities. In your first scenario, player D is the only one with 2 activated knights, so he contributes the most. Your second scenario is correct.

Comment: My bad, for the first scenario, player D gets the 1 VP.

Comment: Then yes, you got it.

Comment: I just wasn't sure because someone told me ONLY if catan has more value than barbarians, then the player with most contribution gets the VP (gets nothing if it's a tie (5vs5). Everytime when I build more knights than my cities, I am covering other player's cities which lead to a tie.. and I never got the VP. That's why I asked.